# MVC Passing in an IEnumerable of longs but on post they don't get bound

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, post

I'm having a little bit of trouble, I have a LINQ query which will put out some data and an IEnumerable of longs. The values from the LINQ query are bound to my model WorkExperience.

Now when the model is passed into the view the select box shows in the HTML code that some options are selected, now when I post the existing selected values don't get posted, however if I select one or de-select one and post the form it will post all of the options selected in the select list. What on earth is going on?

Here are some screenshots to demonstrate

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to see what gets sent over the wire. Use your browsers developer tools to check the request message when is works and when it doesn't. Then you can compare the messages.

Comment: I have used fiddler and it doesn't seem to post the Environments, it only posts them if I change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, basically this project I am working on is with a team mate and he isn't in today, I notice he had some javascript code that would deselect all values on the start of the form, but basically that would select my values, so even in the html displayed it was selected, it wasn't so I basically edited my mates javascript so it would target the specific elements and not just everything. Sorry for this guys.